# New install for Aptana Studio 3 fails to find the JNI shared library

Tags: ruby, aptana

1. Having deleted the Studio 3, which was working, and installing a new one, the first launch produced the message: "Failed to load the JNI Shared Library: 'C:...java.jdk1.8.0_05\bin..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll'"  Upon checking the indicated bin directory, the 'server' subdirectory was missing. I then installed both jre7 and jre8 as standalone jre's. Both hre7 and jre8 have the server subdirectory under bin. If I point JAVA_HOME towards one of the newer installs, I will lose ready access to the JDK. Is there any other way to tell Aptana Studio 3 which jvm to use?
2. This whole exercise was started in an attempt to get Aptana Studio 3 to use Ruby 2.0.0, rather than ruby 1.9.3 (both of which are installed). How might one do that? Both rubys are in the PATH, with ruby2.0.0 first. Also RUBY_HOME points to ruby2.0.0. Entering ruby -v at the command prompt yields 1.9.3.
3. In turn, I am doing this because I am getting a crash in 1.9.3 wich says: "You have encountered a bug in the ruby interpreter..."

Answer (score 6):

You can configure which version of Java Aptana will use in `AptanaStudio3.ini`: simply add

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javaw.exe
```

(before `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`) pointing to a 32bit Java version.

Comment: Note that when using this solution, `-vm` and the path to `javaw.exe` must be on separate, consecutive lines in the .ini file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the 32-bit version of the JDK installed. This error occurs with the 64-bit version. Try and download the 32bit JDK, install and Aptana should run (at least that worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

The latest Windows installer does not contain the JRE, contrary to what the page at http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/success.html says:

> The Windows installer includes a compatible version of Java.

I downloaded the 3.5 installer, installed to a different directory, and copied the JRE directory from there to the 3.6.x directory. This has resolved the issue for me.

(I suppose the installer could contain a 32-bit JRE, detect my system is a 64-bit system, and not install it, but the size difference between the two installers is enough to be accounted for by a missing JRE.)

Answer (score 0):

I Was getting the same issue while loading aptana.
Fixed it with following steps.

1. Uninstalled available jdk7.1 (It was 64 bit)
2. Uninstalled aptana;
3. Downloaded and installed jdk7.1 32 bit.
4. The jvm.dll will be in the follwing path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\bin\client"
5. Re installed aptana

Thanks